# How was Proteus killed so easily?

Tags: penny-dreadful, frankensteins-monster

If Frankenstein's resurrected characters are doomed to be immortal (as Lily clearly is), how was Proteus able to be killed so easily? 
Lily is shot yet it doesn't harm her in the slightest.

Comment: I know nothing about this show, but are these two separate questions?

Comment: Yes, these are two separate questions. Could you edit to focus on one of them, and maybe ask the other separately?

Comment: Immortal is not the same as unkillable/undestroyable

Comment: Why does this have two votes to re-open? This question still contains two questions and is thus "too broad".

Comment: Make them 2 questions as they are things which I would like to know too.

Comment: "Immortal is not the same as unkillable" ... so how come Lily was unaffected by being shot in the heart?!

Comment: @JonChalk - because a bullet wound to flesh is maybe something that would not kill an immortal, but perhaps servering the spinal cord would. Saying that an "immortal" could be killed by something doesn't mean that ALL the same stuff would kill them.  If I could heal major wounds, for example, being blown into tiny pieces and mist by an explosion might be beyond the ability to regenerate.